# Does being in pitch black darkness prevent you from being detected?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

* minor spoilers *

I'm trying to sneak my way underground early to try to find some goodies, and there's a lot. Fortunately it's not densely populated with enemies everywhere. Came across some Yiga strongholds and don't want to alarm them, I don't have a lot of strong weapons. I haven't found the lightroot in the area so it's mostly dark.

Will enemies be able to see me in the darkness or should I just keep out of lines of sight?

Comment: Well, common sense tells that ordinary darkness (i.e. not result of a spell) will not prevent you from being spotted. In some advanced games it might reduce their accuracy, but never seen a game where it prevented enemies from spotting you when you are nearby. However, just a comment as I can't be sure about this specific game. (Played few Zelda games long ago, not this one.)

Comment: I'm talking about pitch black darkness, not just nighttime. Where you can't see a thing without a light source.

Comment: Well you can do trial and error then, and based on several attempts reach a sensible conclusion, which you can then share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my testing, you are just as visible in pitch black darkness as you would be on a bright sunny day to enemies. Standing a decent way away from enemies looking in your direction will alert them like normal. As far as I can see, being in the darkness does not help you avoid detection, so approach with caution as usual.

Comment: Which makes sense for monsters that live underground.  _You_ may be blind but _they_ can see just fine.

Comment: I wouldn't classify Yiga as "monsters," though perhaps it's possible they have night vision tech in their masks. They've been able to spot me, even when their spotlights are not on me.

Comment: @Bobson: Except that the monsters still use torches for light. I'm focusing on Bokoblins and Yiga here, not the Frox.